# Web Audio API, MediaElementAudioSourceNode, Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

I am trying to build a sound player based on Web Audio API. I have an issue with Safari that to me looks like a grave Safari bug, so I don't know if anything can be done about it.

Basically I need to stream an mp3 file into the Web Audio API graph. This goes via `createMediaElementSource`. The problem in Safari (9.1.1) is that everytime one calls `play()` on the underlying `audio` element, the initial audio buffer is corrupted, giving a brief "hiccup". Depending on the complexity of the actual Web Audio graph, these drop outs can last up to several hundred milliseconds. Firefox and Chrome don't have this problem.

The following illustrates the problem. Click on "Load" to set the audio element's `src`. Wait. Then `Play`, `Stop`, `RTZ` (return-to-zero) repeatedly -- you should hear an undistorted sine tone, but you actually hear that the initial buffer upon play is corrupted.

---

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zgf33os/6/

---

HTML:

```
<div id="load" class="button">Load</div>
<div id="play" class="button">Play</div>
<div id="stop" class="button">Stop</div>
<div id="rtz" class="button">RTZ</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var elem = document.createElement("audio");
elem.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
var context = new window.AudioContext;
var node = context.createMediaElementSource(elem);
node.connect(context.destination);
elem.preload = "auto";

elem.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
  alert("Error!");
});

var load = function() {
    elem.src = "https://ia800209.us.archive.org/12/items/SineWaveStudiosSineWaveTestFile/sinetest.mp3";
};
var rtz = function() {
    elem.pause();
  elem.currentTime = 0.0;
};
var play = function() {
    elem.play();
};
var stop = function() {
  elem.pause();
};

$("#load").click(load);
$("#rtz" ).click(rtz );
$("#play").click(play);
$("#stop").click(stop);
```

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple but didn't even receive a confirmation mail or ticket number...